# Azure app service stop working some time

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-web-app-service

I have hosted my client(web application) and service (web api) application on azure portal since 5 to 6 months.

The issue I am facing since the same day hosted my app is when I call my api for the first time to load the dropdownlist from my client side web application it is giving me sometime **timeout error** but sometime it takes more than expected time to get the result from api so client side have to wait for response to come.

After first successful attempt than it runs very fast as expected but for the first time it some time works by getting result late or sometime it throws an timeout error.

I have used scheduler to call the api time to time but this is not helpful as well.

Any other idea which anyone can share it would me nice and thanks in advance.

Comment: @3 rules Did you enable logs like Application insights to find out where the timeout error occurs?

Comment: Have you tried the "Always On" feature of the App Service that can be enabled through Application Settings?

Comment: @Jayendran Yes I have done this already but it only shows me 100% crash of calling one function that gives me the list of data every first time. Where it is running fine.

Comment: @ConnorDickson Yes I have already set it to "Always On"

Comment: @3rules Where the 100% crash occurs? I suspect this crash will be the reason for the timeout error.

Comment: @Jayendran I think so but azure application insight not even show me that problem as well. How to solve this problem of timeout. I access api direct it returns  perfectly fine on time but in client side don't know what is the problem it stops sometime.

Answer (score 13):

You might try to turn on the `Always On` feature under *Application Settings* for the web app:

[image: here's the option]

This ensures that when the site becomes idle, the process doesn't get unloaded (go to sleep):

[image: what does Always On mean?]

It's probably this "sleeping" that's causing the initial request to take longer since it's having to "warm it up" again.

Comment: Thanks for your input but I already did this before still having the same issue.

Comment: Then like others have said, it's most likely in the context of your app. App Insights, New Relic, or other server-side telemetry tools will help you understand the performance and timings of your various components.

Comment: Sir as you suggested I also have did this on the same day when have posted the question and not getting the proper error or issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens only for the first request, it might be related to your Web Application being loaded for the first time. In other words: JIT compiling of your solution, loading dll's: everything to get your application hot and ready to process requests.

One way to go around this is to deploy your code to a slot (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing) on the Web App, get it hot there, and only do swap your deployment slot with the production slot. Assuming you are using VSTS for releases, there are ready made deployment steps for deploying to a slot and swapping slots. Calling your API can easily be done using a Powershell step or an extension for invoking a REST API.

Another, more involved, approach might be using IIS standard features to get your application to warm itself up: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not be the solution but as a best practice with Azure web apps I try to have availability tests done on them through the application insight. For me the main driver of error or lost requests as always been failing availability.

To that avail I also generally build my web apps under a traffic manager, replicated web app and auto-scaling service plans.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the free credit I used in running a resource group expired and all services attached to the group went down. I just upgraded the subscription to pay-as-you-go and everything came back up.